# Applying gaussian noise gives white on colored regions of my image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to apply gaussian noise to this image:

[image: original image]

through this function:

```
def add_noise(image):
    (x, y, channels) = image.shape
    mean = 0
    var = 0.1
    std = np.sqrt(var)
    noise = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=(x, y, channels))
    return image + noise
```

unfortunately this is giving me the following result:

[image: blurred]

As you can see, the noise gets applied only on black regions.

This is the function I use for showing the "noised" image:

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
```

Why is the noise not being applied on the cell itself (i.e. the colored region)?

Moreover, I tried to apply the gaussian noise to the gray-scaled image:

```
def add_noise(image):
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # << added
    (x, y) = image.shape
    mean = 0
    var = 0.1
    std = np.sqrt(var)
    noise = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=(x, y))
    return image + noise
```

Unfortunately this is the result:

[image: noised]

whose result is equivalent to this script:

```
def add_noise(image):
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return image
```

that is, if no noise is added.

Comment: do not tag unrelated technologies. your entire post did not mention OpenCV even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the image values are of integer type, matplotlib supposes a range going from 0 to 255. When you add the noise, you change these to floats. With floats, matplotlib supposes a range between 0 and 1. As most values in the non-black region are larger than 1, they get clipped off and you see the white color.

To just add small float as noise, you could try `return image/255.0 + noise`. This first converts the image from the integer convention to the float convention. Also note that `cmap` is ignored for images with more than 1 channel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to your data type. Pyplot interprets float image data as being scaled between 0 an 1 so it cut offs ecerything above one. this explains the effect. add an `img.astype(np.int)` before plotting

untested from mobile

edit: your noise is so small that it want result in integer changes. So you habe to increase you noise to see differences